# How to calculate a formula involving a reciprocal of a sum of reciprocals on an 8051 microcontroller?

Tags: assembly, 8051

I am trying to solve the mathematical equation in 8051 assembly language. I use the AT89c51 microcontroller and now I am facing some problems of float point numbers. The expression I'm trying to evaluate is `1/(1/X1 + 1/X2)`.

X1 and X2 are variables and when divided 1 by these variables, the result would be float point number and I can't hold it. Meaning I can't continue to solve this equation.

Comment: You might try to rearrange that formula into `(X1 * X2) / (X1 + X2)`

Comment: Please add some details to your question: 1. What are the ranges of `X1` and `X2`? 2. Why don't you use a higher level language that provides `float`s? 3. Did you try the suggested formula of Jester? 4. Did you think about fixed-point floats?

Comment: @thebusybee: 8051 is a low-end 8-bit microcontroller, likely fairly cramped for code-size, I think.  Software `float` emulation is likely highly undesirable for code-size and speed.  But there is a valid point to be made that this question hasn't specified anything about acceptable speed vs. precision tradeoffs, or value-ranges, or types.  (Other than presumably these being integers of some width.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I know, I spent the first 30 years of my career with 8051 derivatives. :-D Code size and speed were rarely problems, but granted, `float`s were also rare.